# editing cell blocks of text, within a pseudo tabular arrangement

Tags: plugin-tabular

I have two closely related questions:

1. Is there a plugin, or a combination of vim commands, that allow
   something analogous to the insertion of a cell in a pseudo tabular
   arrangment of a text file, by "pushing" the old cells down? (as one
   might do  by using a program such as gnumeric).
2. Is it possible to edit a cell, within a pseudo tabular arrangement, 
   thereby increasing the size of the cell block so that it can contain 
   more lines of text?  Naturally, I would like this while preserving 
   the pseudo tabular structure.

My current, very primitive approach to achieving what I want consists in 
putting each column into a separate file, then edit these files together,
side by side, using vim windows, so that one be able to take care of the 
proper vertical alignment, and finally use unix "paste" to merge the 
separate files:

```
paste col1.txt col2.txt col3.txt > table.txt
```

I have tried a few plugins such as "table-mode", which when adding
text to a cell preserves the tabular structure by simply increasing 
the width of the cell, something which is not always satisfactory.

I have also tried "vim-multiedit", which allows the user to "specify
regions of text" and then edit them simultaneously. However the 
emphasis is on doing the editing only once for all regions, and
not on preserving  the "cell/tabular structure".